# Want to get new defects for the sprint, as want to show Defect/Story Ratio

Tags: rally

I have build one app, which shows two things for each team based on selected releases.

1. Rework - Which is Completed Stories in sprint n / Completed stories in sprint n
2. Defect/ Story - New defects in sprint n / Completed stories in sprint n-1

[image]

But I am not able to get which are the **new defects in sprint n**, 
I want the **cumulative activated** count as shown in **Defect Trend Chart**, which I can access from Reports.

Which is a new defect count for me.

Below is my code, where I am considering that defects which are **!ACCEPTED** are new defects but it's not right.

Any help or suggestions on this, how Rally shows **cumulative activated** count as shown in **Defect Trend Chart**?

```
            _fetchByArrayOfValues:function(oids,field_name){
                var filters = null;
                //this.logger.log("_fetchByArrayOfValues (", model_name, ",", oids.length, ",", field_name ,")");
                var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
                filters = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter',{
                    property:field_name,
                    operator: '=',
                    value:oids[0]
                });         
                for ( var i=1;i<oids.length;i++ ) {
                    filters = filters.or(Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter',{
                        property:field_name,
                        value:oids[i]
                    }));
                }
                this.flows_by_iteration_id = {}; // key is iteration_id
                this.iterations = {}; // key is iteration_id
                this.iterations_defined = false;
                //this.old_iterations = {};
                this.addIterations();
                var created = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.artifact.Store', {
                    autoLoad: true,
                    models: ['UserStory','Defect'],
                    context: {
                        project: this.getContext().getProject()._ref,
                        projectScopeDown: true,
                        projectScopeUp: false
                    },                          
                    filters: filters,
                    limit: Infinity,
                    fetch: ['Name','Iteration','ScheduleState', 'InProgressDate', 'LastUpdateDate'],
                    listeners: {
                        load: function(store, records) {
                            var defectHash = {};
                            var storyHash = {};
                            Ext.Array.each(records, function(item){ 
                                var itData = this.iterations[item.data.Iteration._ref];
                                //var id = this.iterations[item.data.Iteration._ref]
                                if ( ! defectHash[itData.Ref] ) { defectHash[itData.Ref] = { "NewCount": 0, "CompletedCount":0}; }
                                if ( ! storyHash[itData.Ref] ) { storyHash[itData.Ref] = { "Count": 0}; }                               
                                if(item.data._type == "defect" && itData.Ref == item.data.Iteration._ref && itData.Name == item.data.Iteration.Name) {
                                    if (item.data.ScheduleState != "Accepted") {
                                        defectHash[itData.Ref].NewCount += 1;
                                    } else if (item.data.ScheduleState == "Accepted") {
                                        defectHash[itData.Ref].CompletedCount += 1;
                                    }
                                    //+= value.Accept;
                                } else if (item.data._type == "hierarchicalrequirement" && item.data.ScheduleState == "Accepted" && itData.Ref == item.data.Iteration._ref && itData.Name == item.data.Iteration.Name) {
                                    storyHash[itData.Ref].Count += 1;
                                }
                            }, this);
                            this.commit_data_set = [defectHash, storyHash];
                            deferred.resolve(created);
                        },  
                        scope: this
                    }
                }, this);
                return deferred.promise;
            },
```